# How to speed up the process of a simple array iteration?

Tags: ruby, arrays, multithreading, performance

My array has 75,000 records and looks like this:

```
orders = [{ :order_id=>"7617",
            :date=>"2014-11-17 19:24:31",
            :firstname=>"Jack",
            :lastname=>"Bauer"},
          { :order_id=>"7618",
            :date=>"2014-11-17 19:34:51",
            :firstname=>"James",
            :lastname=>"Bond"},
            ... ]
```

I now need to loop through this array with the following code:

```
order_id_array = []
order_array    = []

orders.each do |order|
  prepared_order = prepare_order(order)
  order_id_array << prepared_order[0]
  order_array    << prepared_order[1]
end


def prepare_order(order)
  order_id = order[:order_id]

  [ order_id,
    { :order_id => order_id,
      :name => "#{order[:firstname]} #{order[:lastname]}",
      :date => Time.zone.parse(order[:date]),
      :customer_id => Moped::BSON::ObjectId.new } ]
end
```

*This process take about 15 seconds*. That is way way too much. Sometimes my array contains 5M+ hashes.

**How do I speed up this process?**

I have tried to use the [parallel gem](https://github.com/grosser/parallel) like this:

```
Parallel.each(orders, :in_threads => 3){ |order|
  ...
}
```

However, this didn't do anything for me.

Comment: "how do I speed up this process" - step 1 is to find which part is slow.

Comment: I was looking for a more fundamental way of speeding up. I'm not doing much heavy calculation here, so even if I e.g. took out the time parsing I would still be in a situation where I had to iterate over them one by one.

Comment: BTW, did you try threading on MRI? Bad idea. Try JRuby or Rubinius, it may yield better results.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate? Or post an answer?

Comment: You should take a good look at using a database and SQL queries, rather than trying to hold that many elements in an array, especially if it can grow to 5M elements. I'll highly recommend looking at [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/), which would make this an easy task using PostgreSQL or MySQL.

Comment: From an earlier comment I posted on @Mattt's answer, it was obvious the date-time conversion is the bottleneck. I ran three cases, each with `orders` consisting of 300,000 copies of the first hash (`o` below is an element of `orders`). #1: `:datetime => DateTime.parse(o[:date])`, 9.6 seconds. #2 `:datetime => DateTime.strptime(o[:date], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`, 1.3 seconds. #3 `:datetime => DateTime.iso8601(t)` after `t = o[:date]; t[10]='T'`, 3.1 seconds. So you should be able to get a seven-fold improvement just by switching from `parse` to `strptime`.

Comment: ..and #4 `:datetime => DateTime.new(s[0,4].to_i, s[5,2].to_i, s[8,2].to_i, s[11,2].to_i, s[14,2].to_i, s[17,2].to_i )` (where `s=o[:date])`, 1.1 seconds. Considering that `strptime` is written in C, I expected it to be a bit faster than using `new`, but that wasn't the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Profile your code to see what the bottleneck is.

If I had to guess, `Time.zone.parse` is probably where >=80% of the computation is going. Given a fixed date format, you could dramatically improve performance by constructing a date object manually, extracting components from substrings at particular ranges.

Comment: Could you show me how to improve the `Time.zone.parse`? I can't change the fact the the `date` comes in as a string with a timezone that needs to be set.

Comment: @ChristofferJoergensen: you missed the keyword, "if I had to guess" :)

Comment: I was looking for a more fundamental way of speeding up. Everything I do in the `prepare_order` method is necessary, so I was more looking for an answer on how to split up the process.

Comment: Otherwise, could you please remove the answer, so it dosen't look answered.

Comment: Don't split up the processing until you've improved the overall throughput of a single-threaded app. Splitting a poorly performing scripting and running it in multiple threads will only create multiple poorly running scripts. Take the recommendation to work on improving the speed first by learning where the bottlenecks are and fix those. And, yes, `Time.zone.parse` is a major waste of CPU time if you already know what your time format is.

Comment: @ChristofferJoergensen, "could you please remove the answer, so it dosen't look answered."? What? That isn't how Stack Overflow works. The question won't look answered until you, the poster, mark an answer as the "selected" answer. We don't remove answers to make questions look unanswered.

Comment: It's just not really an answer to the question. I intended to ask for a way to split into multiple processes. Maybe I didn't ask the right way, but I didn't intend to ask about how to optimize the DateTime calculation.

Comment: You specifically asked how to speed up the process. We are recommending that you look at the most likely cause of code running slowly, and try fixing that before doing something else. Threads, and running in parallel do not speed things up initially, because they complicate the job, especially when it comes to maintaining synchronizing them, not stomping on common variables, debugging, and maintaining the code. You don't say what OS you are on, but on *nix, create a datastore that allows multiple accesses and then launch multiple instances of your code and let several run at once.

Comment: I ran the OP's code with `orders` consisting of 300,000 copies of the first hash.  It took 10.2 seconds.  After commenting out the line where the parsing is done (after changing that to `:date => Date.parse(order[:date])`) it took 0.4 seconds.  It seems that your estimate was way off. :-)